# Excel repair message generated using ClosedXmL library

Tags: c#

I am using the closedXml library to generate an excel file, when the code is run there is no problem and in the application I download it and it opens the generated excel a repair message appears that I have not been able to solve

This is my code:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> BulkTemplate()
        {
            var user = User.AsUser();
            var companyId = RouteData.Values["companyId"] is Guid guid ? guid : Guid.Parse((string)RouteData.Values["companyId"]);

            var companyTitle = "Company";
            using var ctx = _entityFrameworkContextAccessor.GetContext();
            companyTitle = ctx.Set<Company>().Find(companyId).Title;
            var employees = ctx.Set<Employee>().Where(e => e.CompanyId == companyId && !e.IsDeleted && !e.IsDisable).Select(e => e.Email).ToList();
            var projects = ctx.Set<Project>().Where(p => p.CompanyId == companyId).Select(p => new { ProjectId = p.Id, p.Title }).ToList();
            var tasks = ctx.Set<ProjectTask>().Include(t => t.Project).Where(t => t.Project.CompanyId == companyId).Select(t => new { t.ProjectId, t.Title }).ToList();

            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var wb = new XLWorkbook();
            var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Timesheet");
            ws.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Company";
            ws.Cell(1, 2).Value = "Employee";
            ws.Cell(1, 3).Value = "Project";
            ws.Cell(1, 4).Value = "Task";
            ws.Cell(1, 5).Value = "Date";
            ws.Cell(1, 6).Value = "Hours";

            ws.Cell(2, 1).Value = companyTitle;
            ws.Cell(2, 5).Value = "20/10/2019";
            ws.Cell(2, 6).Value = "8";

            var wsEmployees = wb.Worksheets.Add("Employees");
            if (employees.Count > 0)
                foreach (var r in Enumerable.Range(1, employees.Count))
                {
                    wsEmployees.Cell(r, 1).Value = employees[r - 1];
                }

            var wsProjects = wb.Worksheets.Add("Projects");
            wsProjects.Cell(1, 2).Value = "ProjectId";

            if (projects.Count > 0)
                foreach (var r in Enumerable.Range(1, projects.Count))
                {
                    wsProjects.Cell(r, 1).Value = projects[r - 1].Title;
                    wsProjects.Cell(r, 2).Value = projects[r - 1].ProjectId;
                }

            var wsTasks = wb.Worksheets.Add("Tasks");
            if (tasks.Count > 0)
                foreach (var r in Enumerable.Range(1, tasks.Count))
                {
                    wsTasks.Cell(r, 1).Value = tasks[r - 1].Title;
                    wsTasks.Cell(r, 2).Value = tasks[r - 1].ProjectId;
                    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, projects.Count()))
                    {
                        if (projects[i - 1].ProjectId == tasks[r - 1].ProjectId)
                        {
                            wsTasks.Cell(r, 3).Value = projects[i - 1].Title;
                        }
                    }
                }
            var employeeValidation = ws.Column(2).AsRange().SetDataValidation();
            employeeValidation.List(wsEmployees.Column(1).AsRange(), true);
            employeeValidation.IgnoreBlanks = true;

            var wsTasksValidation = wb.Worksheets.Add("TasksValidation");
            var range = wsTasksValidation.Range(1, 2, tasks.Count() + 1, projects.Count());
            for (int i = 1; i <= projects.Count(); i++)
            {
                range.Cell(1, i).Value = projects[i - 1].Title;
                string title = projects[i - 1].Title;
                string[] titleParts = title.Split(' ');
                string namedRange = string.Join("_", titleParts);
                var projectTasks = tasks.Where(t => t.ProjectId == projects[i - 1].ProjectId).ToList();
                var rangeNames = wsTasksValidation.Range(2, i + 1, projectTasks.Count() + 1, i + 1);
                rangeNames.AddToNamed(namedRange);
            }
            foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, projects.Count()))
            {
                var project = projects[i - 1];
                var projectTasks = tasks.Where(t => t.ProjectId == project.ProjectId).ToList();
                for (int r = 1; r <= tasks.Count(); r++)
                {
                    if (r <= projectTasks.Count)
                    {
                        var task = projectTasks[r - 1];
                        range.Cell(r + 1, i).Value = task.Title;
                    }
                }
            }

            wsTasksValidation.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Projects1";
            int w = 1;
            foreach (var a in projects)
            {
                wsTasksValidation.Cell(++w, 1).Value = a.Title;
            }
            wsTasksValidation.Range("A2:A" + w).AddToNamed("Projects1");
            ws.Column(3).SetDataValidation().List(wsTasksValidation.Range("Projects1"), true);
            ws.Column(4).SetDataValidation().InCellDropdown = true;
            ws.Column(4).SetDataValidation().Operator = XLOperator.Between;
            ws.Column(4).SetDataValidation().AllowedValues = XLAllowedValues.List;
            ws.Column(4).SetDataValidation().List("=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(C1," + '"' + " " + '"' + "," + '"' + "_" + '"' + "))");

            wb.SaveAs(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return File(ms, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", $"timesheet.xlsx");
        }
```

I have tried removing these two lines and Excel does not show the repair

```
ws.Column(4).SetDataValidation().AllowedValues = XLAllowedValues.List;
ws.Column(4).SetDataValidation().List("=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(C1," + '"' + " " + '"' + "," + '"' + "_" + '"' + "))");
```

but these lines are essential for the cascade operation of the cells that I have in Excel to work...

On the other hand, Excel when closing the repair message works optimally, without any inconvenience, especially the cells that are in cascade and that have the dropdown...

This is the repair message appears:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try putting ms in a using block: `using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {` or if you have C#  8.0 + `using var ms = new MemoryStream();`.

Comment: Have you tried running with the XLAllowedValues.List line and not the substitution line? The error may be coming from the substitution itself and/or the creation of an invalid reference. Also, Have you tried to allow the repair to occur and look at the resulting repaired file to see what it repaired. That may also hold a clue..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error was that the Excel was corrupted when I was defining a range it took an entire column, it helped me to place only 10,000 rows in ranges.

ws.Range(2, 4, 10000, 4).SetDataValidation().InCellDropdown = true;
ws.Range(2, 4, 10000, 4).SetDataValidation().Operator = XLOperator.Between;
ws.Range(2, 4, 10000, 4).SetDataValidation().AllowedValues = XLAllowedValues.List;
var taskValidation = ws.Range(2, 4, 10000, 4).SetDataValidation();